# Image segmentation using corresponding masks in python

Tags: python, for-loop, image-processing, machine-learning, image-segmentation

I have corresponding masks to the images that I want to segment.

I put the images in one folder and their corresponding masks in another folder.
I'm trying to apply those masks or multiply them by the images using two for loops in python to get the segmented images.

I'm using the code below:

```
def ImageSegmentation():

SegmentedImages = []

for img_path in os.listdir('C:/Users/mab/Desktop/images/'):
    img=io.imread('C:/Users/mab/Desktop/data/'+img_path)
    for img_path2 in os.listdir('C:/Users/mab/Desktop/masks/'):
        Mask = io.imread('C:/Users/mab/Desktop/masks/'+img_path2)

        [indx, indy] = np.where(Mask==0)
        Color_Masked = img.copy()
        Color_Masked[indx,indy] = 0

        matplotlib.image.imsave('C:/Users/mab/Desktop/SegmentedImages/'+img_path2,Color_Masked)
        segs.append(Color_Masked)
 return np.vstack(Color_Masked)
```

This code works when I try it for a single image and a single mask (without the folders and loops).

However, when I try to loop over the images and masks I have in the two folders, I get output images that are segmented by the wrong mask (not their corresponding mask).

I can't segment each single image alone without looping because I have more than 500 Images and their masks.

I don't know what I'm missing or placing wrong in this code and how can I fix it? Also, is there an easier way to get the segmented images?

Comment: Stop. Think! If there are 10 images and 10 masks and you run 2 nested loops, you will get 100 output images... probably wrong. Instead, change directory to where the images are and glob, or list, all the files in a single loop. Form the single name of the corresponding mask just once for each image using `os.joinpath()`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for replying. I tried to do a single loop and I added `os.path.join` and I used the glob for images, but I get a Permission Error to open the masks folder and the images folder too. Also, what did you mean by your last sentence 'from the single name of the corresponding..'? How do I specify the single name exactly without a loop? Did you mean a glob for images without a loop and a for loop for the masks?

Comment: I mean have a single loop that reads one input image and one mask and produces one output image each time through the loop.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I see. But what would be the index or the variable that changes to read all the masks or the images to read one image at a time? I tried glob for images and then a for loop that reads masks and goes through the glob of images but got a permission error again.

Comment: If you have 10 images and 10 masks, how many output images do you expect? If the answer is 10, you need 1 loop. If the answer is 100, you need two nested loops.

Comment: Ok. Thank you.  Lastly, what would I be looping over in the 1 loop?

Comment: Personally, I would loop over the input images, and then, knowing the name of an image I would deduce the name of the corresponding mask and open that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's what I'm trying to figure out because the corresponding mask is in another folder. Thanks I will see.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have grossly misunderstood, you just need something like this:

```
import glob

filelist = glob.glob('C:/Users/mab/Desktop/images/*.png') 
for i in filelist:
    mask = i.replace("images","masks")
    print(i,mask)
```

On my iMac, that sort of thing produces:

```
/Users/mark/StackOverflow/images/b.png /Users/mark/StackOverflow/masks/b.png
/Users/mark/StackOverflow/images/a.png /Users/mark/StackOverflow/masks/a.png
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer. Now I'm getting a 'ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)'.  I think the files aren't being read.

Comment: It is probably easiest to debug with `ipython`. Just start `ipython` and type in the first line of my code. Then copy and paste in the second line. Then type `filelist` and hit Enter/Return and you will see the contents of `filelist`. Check they look correct. Now type in the line beginning `for...` and hit Enter...

Comment: I am using Ipython. I will try again. Thank you.